# spring boot database not inizialising or updating

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

I have following config in my `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

My project is based on gradle (auto updating every library: `:+`)

The `src/data.sql` is not launched on start and the update does not add new tables.

```
o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000126: Indexes: [primary_key_1, uk_4ljg0yv562w61cve37tou1fqu_index_1]
java.sql.DatabaseMetaData                : HHH000262: Table not found: Pokemon_eigenschaften
java.sql.DatabaseMetaData                : HHH000262: Table not found: Pokemon_eigenschaften
java.sql.DatabaseMetaData                : HHH000262: Table not found: Pokemon_eigenschaften
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000232: Schema update complete
```

My team members are using eclipse and there it is working.

Comment: Why on Earth are those keys duplicated with different values?!

Comment: I see you've edited the description. That was just a typo then I guess. Where is the `data.sql` located exactly?

Comment: Does it work if you start the application via command line using gradle (gradle bootRun)?